# ViewController with edges that does not extend under top and bottom bars but still have translucent navigation bar

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have a view controller designed for iOS7, using Storyboards which has a Navigation bar, a tab bar and a web view.

If I select NOT to extend edges under Top and Bottom bars for this view, I lose the translucent effect of the the navigation bar and the tab bar.

If i select to extend edges my webview goes under the navigation bar and the tab bar.

How can I do both? Meaning have both the translucency AND no extension under the bars?

Comment: have you tried setting the translucent property on navigation bar?

Comment: Yes, but If I uncheck the boxes for Extend Edges under bars, the bars remain non-translucent